# How to typeset gotos and labels using LaTeX pseudocode environments?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

Is there any way to typeset gotos and labels using LaTeX pseudocode environments (`algorithmic`, `pseudocode`, `clrscode`, `algorithm2e`, etc.)? Automatic and correct indentation of labels would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: But gotos aren't indented, and if you are using them in such a consistent way, you could replace them with an equivalent while-loop easily.

Comment: Doesn't listings have a layout tool for this? Some of the 'howto' examples are in psudocode, aren't they?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the line numbers to act as your labels, and reference them in a "go to" command.

In the following minimal example, I've defined a "go to" command using the following (I'm using [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmx)):

```
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}%
```

`\algorithmicgoto` provides the style, while `\Goto{<label>}` is the actual command to be used inside the `algorithmic` environment. Here `<label>` is a label defined on any line using `\label{<label>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\begin{document}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}%
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0} \label{marker}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \State \Goto{marker}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

It is also possible combine the `\State` command in `\Goto` using:

```
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\State \algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}
```

However, this would make it impossible to use `\Goto` with anything else on a line, since it issues a `\State`, which starts a new line in the algorithm.

---

Here is another approach, still using `algorithmicx`. This time I've used a slightly different version of `\Goto` (using [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace)). Additionally there's a `\Label` command defined. This issues a `\State` command, followed by `\unskip` which removed any horizontal skip issued internally by `algorithmicx` to indent the block by the appropriate amount. This allows you to typeset "labels" flush to the left margin in your own style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\begin{document}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}{\algorithmicgoto\xspace}%
\algnewcommand{\Label}{\State\unskip}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \Label \texttt{marker:}
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \State \Goto \texttt{marker}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One can also use `\algnewcommand\Label[1]{\item[#1:]}`. The second approach you've described seems to me to be more idiomatically correct, though.

Answer (score 7):

When using `algorithm2e` I used code line the one bellow for `Goto`

```
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
    \small
    \SetAlgoNoLine
    \LinesNumbered
    \SetKw{KwGoTo}{go to}

    \Begin{
        \For{$i = 1$ \KwTo $L$}{\label{outer_loop}
            \For{$k = 1$ \KwTo $K$} {
                \If{$k = 10$}{
                    \KwGoTo \ref{outer_loop}\;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: When the algorithm has a caption and I use the label I get the following error:`! Paragraph ended before \caption@@xlabel was complete.`