# How can I put a curly brace inside an algorithm to group code lines?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, braces

I am using the `algorithmic` package (or even `algorithm2e` is fine). Is it possible to use curly braces to group some lines in the algorithm so as to be able to put an explanation to the right?

Comment: If you search for `brace` and `text` in this site, a lot of possibilities show up.

Comment: Would you please add an example, complete with a minimal preamble, from which to start?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is an example using the infamous `\tikzmark` macro applied to the example from [How to typeset gotos and labels using LaTeX pseudocode environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33784/how-to-typeset-gotos-and-labels-using-latex-pseudocode-environments).

[image]

### Usage:

- Mark the horizontal position with: `\tikzmark{right}`.  Here I used the end of the header `procedure Euclid(a,b) as the` right` node.  Hence the horizontal position of the brace.
- Mark the top of the brace with: `\tikzmark{top}`.
- Mark the bottom of the brace with `\tikzmark{bottom}`.
- Call `\AddNote{<top node>}{<bottom node>}{<right node>}{<text>}`.

These node names `top`, `bottom`, and `right` are arbitrary so if you have multiple places in the same algorithm where you want to place such notes, you can use different node names.  Just pass them to the `\AddNote` macro.

## Notes:

- This does require two runs. First one to determine the locations, and the second to do the drawing.

### Further Enhancements:

- The macro `\AddNote` could accept additional formatting parameters for the text of the node, and line color selection. Currently this is hard coded to used `red` and `text width=2.5cm`.

## References:

- `\tikzmark` is from [Adding a large brace next to a body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1570/4301).

Here are a few similar applications using `\tikzmark`:

- [Curly brace to insert something into an equation? Like an inverted underbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47017/curly-brace-to-insert-something-into-an-equation-like-an-inverted-underbrace/47032#47032)
- [Adding Arrows to Lines Drawn in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41494/adding-arrows-to-lines-drawn-in-tikz/41502#41502)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red]
            ($(#3)!(#1.north)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --  
            ($(#3)!(#2.south)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
                node [align=center, text width=2.5cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\begin{document}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}%
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\tikzmark{right}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$} \tikzmark{top}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0} \label{marker}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile \tikzmark{bottom}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \State \Goto{marker}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\AddNote{top}{bottom}{right}{We loop here until $r=0$.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me, what `($(#3)!(#1.north)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)` does?

Comment: @Matthias: Good question. Have a look at `13.5.5 The Syntax of Projection Modifiers` of the tikz-pgf manual. This would make an great follow up question as I had totally forgotten this syntax as I don't use it very often.

Comment: Note that, at least in `algorithm2e`, the `\AddNote` command needs to be inside the algorithm environment (as in the MWE)

Comment: @Jon: Yes, it needs to stay _with_ the float and get executed on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more traditional way of performing this bracketed grouping (using Peter's example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\begin{document}
\algnewcommand{\algorithmicgoto}{\textbf{go to}}%
\algnewcommand{\Goto}[1]{\algorithmicgoto~\ref{#1}}%
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}\label{marker}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$\hspace*{4em}%
        \rlap{\smash{$\left.\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\\{}\\{}\\{}\\{}\end{array}\color{red}\right\}%
          \color{red}\begin{tabular}{l}We loop here\\until $r=0$.\end{tabular}$}}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \State \Goto{marker}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The approach is similar to that described in [A set of equations, vertically aligned, individually tagged, with subequations, and separate label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50965/5764). The idea is to create a zero-height object (an appropriately-sized, `\smash`ed `array`) at the correct location (line 5 in this example) and let LaTeX do the rest.

Comment: This approach makes maintaining the code a hassle; if you add two extra lines to the while-loop, you also need to both move the `\rlap` command to the new center line, as well as add `\\{}\\{}` to it. And what if you add just one extra line to the while-loop—where would you even place the `\rlap` command in that case, as when you have an even number of lines, there is no center line?

Comment: For an even number of lines, put the code just below the middle and move it up adding `\raisebox{\dimexpr.5\normalbaselineskip+.5\jot}` in the argument of `\smash`