# Source code explanation in LaTeX

Tags: listings, minted, source

I was just wondering if it is possible to create source code explanations like the image below using LaTeX (listings or minted it doesn't matter). I'm Sorry I'm kind of new to LaTeX.

[image: source code with explanation next to it]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Should be possible with a well-placed `\tikzmark`

Comment: At first glance this package does look like it would get the job done; thanks.

Comment: I am working on a revision to my `verbatimbox` package that will allow this sort of thing (after a fashion).  When I post the update to CTAN, I will likewise provide an answer here, though it could be a few weeks more.  And of course, it does not use the `listings` approach, if you are wedded to that.

Comment: Could you please check whether [Macros for code annotations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86309/13304) helps? In case, we might probably close this question as duplicated of the linked on if you agree.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino yes it actually helps a lot, closing this question does seem the right thing to do. thank you.