# Source code annotation line by line

Tags: listings, annotations

I'm need to annotate source code line by line using the listings package. Here's an example of what I'm looking for (made in MS Word):
[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

These particular examples display price of executing each line (left column) and how many times it is being called (right column).

Here's what I got going on so far (nothing done on annotations, as I'm not sure where to even start):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++,caption=Insertion sort realizacija masyve]
std::vector<int> insertion_sort_array::sort(const std::vector<int> &in) {
    std::vector<int> res(in);

    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 1; i < res.size(); i++) {
        for (std::size_t j = i; j > 0 && res[j - 1] > res[j]; j--) {
            int tmp = res[j - 1];
            res[j - 1] = res[j];
            res[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition to the screenshot of the code listing, please post the LaTeX code that gives rise to the screenshot. Also, please indicate which document class you employ and which packages you load.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made the changes you requested but I'm afraid they're not going to be of much help.

Comment: Maybe one can use a three-column table and imitate the look of a listing?!

Comment: Sounds like a job for `tikzmark`.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86309/86 for how tikzmark and listings integrate.

Answer (score 6):

This follows up on the linked answer for tikzmark and listings.  In your example's preamble, add

```
\usepackage[left=.5in,width=5.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\newcommand{\annot}[3]{
 \node at ( {pic cs:line-texcode-#1-end} -| {current page marginpar area.east}) [left] {#2};
 \node at ( {pic cs:line-texcode-#1-end} -| {current page marginpar area.east}) [right] {#3};
}
% usage: \annot{line-number}{left remark}{right remark}
```

Then after the listing environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 % draw the vertical line
 \draw ( {pic cs:line-texcode-1-start} -| {current page marginpar area.east})
  -- ( {pic cs:line-texcode-13-end} -| {current page marginpar area.east});
 \annot{1}{Kaine}{Kartai}
 \annot{2}{$c_1$}{$1$}
 \annot{4}{$T_L(\mathrm{res})$}{$1$}
 \annot{6}{$c_2$}{$\mathrm{res.length}+1$}
 \annot{7}{$c_3$}{$\sum_{i=1}^{\mathrm{res.length}}\sum_{j=0}^i 1$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in:

[image: screen shot of output]

I'm not entirely satisfied with the spacing, but I don't know enough about geometry, listings, and tikz.

Comment: It's a good start for a complete answer.

Comment: Instead of `left` and `right` you may work with anchors and in addition use `xshift` but I also think the answer is quite nice. (+1)