# How can I put a curly brace inside a listing to group code lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings

I am using the listing package. Is it possible to use curly braces to group some lines in the listing so as to be able to put an explanation to the right?

I'm trying to use the code given in [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill)'s excellent answer to [How can I put a curly brace inside an algorithm to group code lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines) but passing the markers given by tikzmark's listings capability to AddNote doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc,tikzmark}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}

\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red]
            ($(#3)!(#1.north)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --  
            ($(#3)!(#2.south)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
                node [align=center, text width=2.5cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=listing]
  Example code line 1
  Example code line 2
  Example code line 3
  Example code line 4
  Example code line 5
  Example code line 6
  Example code line 7
  Example code line 8
  Example code line 9
  Example code line 10
\end{lstlisting}

\AddNote{pic cs:line-listing-4-end}{pic cs:line-listing-7-end}{pic cs:line-listing-4-end}{Example annotation.}
\end{document}
```

And here's what that outputs:

[image]

Comment: Is that how you reference lines in listings?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. It does require a recompile for the positions to sync up completeley, but I have used it successfully for annotating listings with just arrows. Page 8 of the Tikzmark documentation outlines it a bit: ftp://ctan.sharelatex.com/pub/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf @Alenanno

Answer (score 5):

Many things have likely changed since this question was asked. I'm not entirely sure why your usage is not working, since it matches what is listed in the documentation. Maybe some incompatibility cropped up in recent updates.

Anyway, here is a workaround using `listings`' `mathescape` feature, but maybe someone will come along with a real answer, and I will delete this answer then.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate,ultra thick,red]
            ($(#3)!([yshift=1.5ex]#1)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --  
            ($(#3)!(#2)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
                node [align=center, text width=2.5cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
  Example code line 1
  Example code line 2
  Example code line 3
  Example code line 4 $\tikzmark{listing-4-end}$
  Example code line 5
  Example code line 6
  Example code line 7   $\tikzmark{listing-7-end}$
  Example code line 8
  Example code line 9
  Example code line 10
\end{lstlisting}

\AddNote{listing-4-end}{listing-7-end}{listing-4-end}{Example annotation.}
\end{document}
```

Remember that these math escapes are placed literally (whitespace matters). So the horizontal position is still controlled by the third argument to `\AddNote`, but you must add/remove whitespace before the math escape to change the position.

### Output

[image]

Comment: Works for me `:)` I wouldn't delete this answer, if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

Working on @PaulGessler code, I've come up with another solution.

The only major advantage is that in this case we must not define which one of the two marks (inside the code) is the rightmost. This is achieved by fitting a `rectangle` (with no color) around those positions, and drawing the `brace` along its `east` side.

One macro is included: `drawBrace`. It can receive an optional parameter, setting the horizontal shift the brace will be drawn, relative to the `rectangle` formed by the two marks in the code.

The code produces two examples, the only difference is how the nodes and arrows are styled inside their `tikzpicture`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,fit}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2][]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=-.5ex] \node[#1] (#2) {};%
}

% \drawBrace[xshift]{beginningNode}{endingNode}
% This command draws a brace between two tikzmarks, to their right,
% no matter which one is the rightmost, and includes 
% a node midway the brace, to write the comment.
% This command also creates a new node
% whose name is the concat of the names of beginning and ending nodes.
\newcommand*{\drawBrace}[4][0pt]{%
    \node[draw=none, fit={(#2) (#3)}, inner sep=0pt] (rectg) {};%
    \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.3em},decorate,very thick,red]%
      ([xshift=#1]rectg.north east) --%
      coordinate[right=1em, midway] (#2#3)
      ([xshift=#1]rectg.south east);%
    \node[right=1.5em of #2#3] (#2#3-comment) {#4};
    \draw (#2#3-comment.west) edge (#2#3);
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=listing,escapechar=!]
  Example code line 1 !\tikzmark{bgnShifted}!
  Example code line 2
  Example code line 3
  Example code line 4 !\tikzmark{bgnBrace}\tikzmark{trmShifted}!
  Example code line 5
  Example code line 6
  Example code line 7 !\tikzmark{trmBrace}!
  Example code line 8
  Example code line 9 !\tikzmark{bgnOther}!
  Example code line 10 !\tikzmark{trmOther}!
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \drawBrace[.6em]{bgnShifted}{trmShifted}{Example xshifted.};
    \drawBrace{bgnBrace}{trmBrace}{Example annotation.};
    \drawBrace{bgnOther}{trmOther}{Another example.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=listing,escapechar=!]
  Example code line 1 !\tikzmark{bgnShifted}!
  Example code line 2
  Example code line 3
  Example code line 4 !\tikzmark{bgnBrace}\tikzmark{trmShifted}!
  Example code line 5
  Example code line 6
  Example code line 7 !\tikzmark{trmBrace}!
  Example code line 8
  Example code line 9 !\tikzmark{bgnOther}!
  Example code line 10 !\tikzmark{trmOther}!
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
    every edge/.append style = { ->, thick, >=stealth, red!70},
    every node/.style={draw=red,red,rounded corners}]
    \drawBrace[.6em]{bgnShifted}{trmShifted}{Example xshifted.};
    \drawBrace{bgnBrace}{trmBrace}{Example annotation.};
    \drawBrace{bgnOther}{trmOther}{Another example.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice and working. So helpful!