# Getting error while using top, and right braces in a listing

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, braces

I am showing right and top braces, whereas while attempting to add overbraces using a new function called 'AddNoteOver', I am getting this error: *"Package tikz Error: + or - expected ...sting-1-start}{listing-1-end}{overbrace!.}"*  , my file is interpreted, though!.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.7em},decorate, thick,black]
            ($(#3)!([yshift=1.5ex]#1)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --  
            ($(#3)!(#2)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
                node [align=center, text width=3cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\newcommand*{\AddNoteOver}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate, thick,black]
            {($($(#1).north west$)-(0,-0.3)$) -- ($($(#2).north east$)-(0,-0.3)$) node [align=center, text width=3cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west,above=3mm] {#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\fontsize{7}{8}\ttfamily},mathescape,
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language=Java,
numbersep=1pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
public  $\tikzmark{listing-1-start}$ PersistentJournal(PrevaylerDirectory directory)  $\tikzmark{listing-1-end}$
 throws IOException {
        PrevaylerDirectory.checkValidJournalSuffix(journalSuffix); $\tikzmark{listing-4-end}$
        _monitor = monitor;
        _directory = directory;
        _directory.produceDirectory();s;
        _journalSuffix = journalSuffix;                            $\tikzmark{listing-7-end}$
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\AddNote{listing-4-end}{listing-7-end}{listing-4-end}{Right Brace!.}
\AddNoteOver{listing-1-start}{listing-1-end}{overbrace!.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For this, I would suggest you to use the `tikzmark` package with his library devoted to listings.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141892/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-a-listing-to-group-code-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few mistakes in your `\AddNoteOver`.  The main one being `(#1).north west` should not have the `()`, so should be `#1.north west`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `AddNote` is from [How can I put a curly brace inside an algorithm to group code lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines/51037#51037).

### Code:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51019/how-can-i-put-a-curly-brace-inside-an-algorithm-to-group-code-lines/51037#51037
\newcommand*{\AddNote}[4]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.7em},decorate, thick,black]
            ($(#3)!([yshift=1.5ex]#1)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$) --  
            ($(#3)!(#2)!($(#3)-(0,1)$)$)
                node [align=center, text width=3cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west] {#4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}%

\newcommand*{\AddNoteOver}[3]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [decoration={brace,amplitude=0.5em},decorate, thick,black]
            {($(#1.north west)-(0,-0.3)$) -- ($(#2.north east)-(0,-0.3)$) node [align=center, text width=3cm, pos=0.5, anchor=west,above=3mm] {#3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace{1.0cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\fontsize{7}{8}\ttfamily},mathescape,
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language=Java,
numbersep=1pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run},
]
public  $\tikzmark{listing-1-start}$ PersistentJournal(PrevaylerDirectory directory)  $\tikzmark{listing-1-end}$
 throws IOException {
        PrevaylerDirectory.checkValidJournalSuffix(journalSuffix); $\tikzmark{listing-4-end}$
        _monitor = monitor;
        _directory = directory;
        _directory.produceDirectory();s;
        _journalSuffix = journalSuffix;                            $\tikzmark{listing-7-end}$
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\AddNote{listing-4-end}{listing-7-end}{listing-4-end}{Right Brace!.}
\AddNoteOver{listing-1-start}{listing-1-end}{overbrace!.}

\end{document}
```